# Content of a polynomial and maximal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-spaces, principal-ideal-domains

I have the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a PID. Let us denote for $P=a_0+a_1 X+\dots+a_n X^n\in R[X]$ that $c(P)=\gcd(a_0,...,a_n)$. Show that for $P\in R[X]$ nonzero $c(P)=1$ iff for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ the morphism $$R[X]\rightarrow R/\mathfrak{p}[X]$$ sends $P$ to a nonzero element.

I first wanted to show $\Leftarrow$ direction, and my Idea was to do it by contraposition. So assume that $c(P)\neq 1$, i.e. $c(P)\not \in R^\times$ so not invertible. Then we know that $(c(P))\subset R$. Since this is a strict ideal we know from the lecture that there is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ such that $(c(P))\subset \mathfrak{p}$. Then I somehow don't see how to conclude, so I think I should show that the image of $P$ is in the same equivalence class as $\mathfrak{p}$ because then it would map to zero and we would get the negation of the second statement.

**Remark.** In the solution they wrote something like $p\in \mathfrak{p}R[X]$ and that's the negation of the second statement, but I first don't understand how to get there and then also what does $\mathfrak{p}R[X]$ mean.

Can someone help me? It would be nice if we would continue with the Proof above because till this point I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You are done. Because $(c(P))\subset\mathfrak p$ implies $a_i\in\mathfrak p$ for all $i$, hence $P\text{ mod }\mathfrak p = 0$.

Comment: so but in $P$ there are also $X^i$ isn't this also important

Comment: No. You have to understand the obvious morphism $R[x]\rightarrow R/\mathfrak p [x]$ sends coefficient $a_i$ to the coset $a_i + \mathfrak p$ and $x$ to $x$ itself.

Comment: but in $R[X]$ aren't there also whole polynomials? And what do you mean by $X$ to $X$ itself? so isn't $X$ an element of $R$? Sorry I have a bit a mess here and it would be nice if I could understand this a bit better

Comment: You need to read the construction of polynomial rings $R[X]$ which consists of (formal) polynomials of $X$. $X$ is just a symbol, whether in $R[X]$ or $R/\mathfrak p [X]$. (I don't understand what you mean by "whole polynomials"?)

Comment: so we haven't constructed it

Comment: we have only written that in $R[X]$ elements are of the form $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i X^i$$ where $(a_i)_{i\in I}\subset R$ is a family with finite support.